# Swift - Group an array of items by week of year

Tags: arrays, swift, date, multidimensional-array, mapping

I'm currently trying to manipulate an array of objects that takes a date, double, and string values for the whole year. Im trying to group/add all items that share the same week and name. Currently it doesn't do that, it just adds up all the qty of each item for the week and ends up printing that output twice.

I've tried using multiple .mapvalues and got close to what my goal, but I'm confused how to add/group together items that share the same week and name for each location.

`Current OutPut:`
`["Location1": ["Location1": [1: 12.0], "Location#2": [3: 16.0]], "Location2": ["Location1": [1: 12.0], "Location#2": [3: 16.0]]]`

`Goal:`
`["Location1": [1: ["Apple": 5, "Pear": 7]], "Location2": [2: ["Apple": 7, "Pear": 9]]`
`//["Location": weekOfYear: ["itemName": qtySold]]`

```
import Foundation

let cal = Calendar.current

extension Date {
    
    var week: Int {
        return cal.component(.weekOfYear, from: self)
    }
    var weekAndYear: DateComponents {
        return cal.dateComponents([.weekOfYear, .yearForWeekOfYear], from: self)
    }
    
    var yearForWeekOfYear: Int {
        return cal.component(.yearForWeekOfYear, from: self)
    }
}

struct sortedDates {
    var date: Date
    var itemName: String
    var itemSold: Double
}

//Current Dates in String Form
let date1 = "\(2023)-\(01)-\(04)"
let date2 = "\(2023)-\(01)-\(05)"
let date3 = "\(2023)-\(01)-\(06)"
let date4 = "\(2023)-\(01)-\(17)"
let date5 = "\(2023)-\(01)-\(18)"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

//Dates in String Form converted to Date
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let dateForm1 = dateFormatter.date(from: date1)
let dateForm2 = dateFormatter.date(from: date2)
let dateForm3 = dateFormatter.date(from: date3)
let dateForm4 = dateFormatter.date(from: date4)
let dateForm5 = dateFormatter.date(from: date5)

//locations and Items
let allLocations = ["Location1", "Location2"]
let allItems = ["Apple", "Pear"]

//List of Data
let allInfo: [String: [sortedDates]] = ["Location1": [sortedDates(date: dateForm1 ?? Date(), itemName: "Apple", itemSold: 3.0), sortedDates(date: dateForm2 ?? Date(), itemName: "Pear", itemSold: 7), sortedDates(date: dateForm3 ?? Date(), itemName: "Apple", itemSold: 2)], "Location#2": [sortedDates(date: dateForm4 ?? Date(), itemName: "Apple", itemSold: 7), sortedDates(date: dateForm5 ?? Date(), itemName: "Pear", itemSold: 9)]]

//Dict in which final results will be held.
var tempDict: [String: Any] = [:]

//Loop through each location and groups items together
for curLocation in allLocations {
    
    let grouppedByYearThenWeek = allInfo
        .mapValues{(yearArray: [sortedDates]) -> Dictionary<Int, Double> in
            return Dictionary(grouping: yearArray, by: { $0.date.week })
                .mapValues{ (value: [sortedDates]) in
                    return value.map{ $0.itemSold }.reduce(0,+)
                }
        }
    
        if tempDict[curLocation] == nil {
            tempDict[curLocation] = []
        }
        
        tempDict[curLocation] = grouppedByYearThenWeek
}

print(tempDict)
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by breaking it down into two problems to solve and then combined the solutions. First we have the arrays in the starting dictionary `allInfo`, for instance

```
let array = [SortedDate(date: dateForm4, itemName: "Apple", itemSold: 7), SortedDate(date: dateForm5, itemName: "Pear", itemSold: 9)]
```

We can sum the values per name using `reduce(into:)` and group by week by using `Dictionary(grouping:by:)`

```
Dictionary(grouping: array, by: \.date.week).mapValues { $0.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.itemName, default: 0] += $1.itemSold} }
```

This would give us the correct result for that particular value in the array

> [3: ["Apple": 7.0, "Pear": 9.0]]

Now we only need to apply this to each value in the dictionary

```
var result: [String: [Int: [String: Double]]] = [:]

allInfo.forEach { (key, value) in
    result[key] = Dictionary(grouping: value, by: \.date.week).mapValues { values in
        values.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.itemName, default: 0] += $1.itemSold }
    }
}
```

> ["Location1": [1: ["Apple": 5.0, "Pear": 7.0]], "Location2": [3: ["Apple": 7.0, "Pear": 9.0]]]

Comment: Note that I changed sortedDates to SortedDate to follow common practice in swift for naming types